# Загрузка нескольких файлов на сервер php

Tags: php

Подскажите как загрузить на сервер и в базу данных несколько картинок. Ниже привел код у меня не получилось, подскажите как поправить код чтобы можно было загрузить несколько картинок. В Базу я загружаю пути файлов, формат примерно такой /i/название_картинки.jpg

1. В бд есть два поля id (int 10 A_U) и name(varchar 255).
   код формы

   Выберите файл для загрузки:

вывел массив

```
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{ 
    ?><pre><?print_r ($_FILES['userfile']['name']);?></pre>
    <?
}
```

получил такой вид

```
Array
(
    [0] => nRLOalVq36k.jpg
    [1] => t1.jpg
    [2] => t2.jpg
)
```

прочитал статьи где написано что нужно циклом записывать данные. Попробовал так

```
if(!empty($_POST) && !empty($_FILES)){
 
$uploaddir = '/i/';
foreach ($_FILES['userfile']['name'] as $k=>$v){

if(($_FILES['userfile']['type'] == 'image/gif' || $_FILES['userfile']['type'] == 'image/jpeg' || $_FILES['userfile']['type'] == 'image/png') && ($_FILES['userfile']['size'] != 0 and $_FILES['userfile']['size']<=1024000))
{
    $ex = explode('.',$_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    $ex= end($ex);
    $apend=date('YmdHis').rand(100,1000).'.'.$ex;
    $uploadfile = "$uploaddir$apend";
    file_put_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/_.txt","\n\r".__FILE__.":".__LINE__."\n\r".print_r($uploadfile,true));
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT].$uploadfile))
   {
        $c="INSERT INTO images (name) VALUES('$uploadfile') ";
        $q=$dbh->prepare($c);
       
        $q->execute();
        
    }       echo $uploadfile;
} 
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас множественная загрузка файлов, о чем говорит параметр `multiple` в инпуте.

```
if(($_FILES['userfile']['type'] == 'image/gif' || $_FILES['userfile']['type'] == 'image/jpeg' || $_FILES['userfile']['type'] == 'image/png') && ($_FILES['userfile']['size'] != 0 and $_FILES['userfile']['size']<=1024000))
```

Это условие не проходит проверку, так как все эти элементы - массивы значений, а не значения. 
Напишите

```
var_dump($_FILES['userfile']['type']);
```

сразу после проверки и поймете о чем я говорю.

Вам нужно подставить индекс обрабатываемого в данный момент файла (в Вашем случае `$k`)

```
if(($_FILES['userfile']['type']**[$k]** == 'image/gif' || //и так далее
```

а еще сюда

```
$ex = explode('.',$_FILES['userfile']['name']**[$k]**);
```

и сюда

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']**[$k]**,  //и так далее
```

Не стал длинные строки целиком писать, чтоб лучше было видно, что пропустили в коде